# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, sql, long-integer

I want to return number of rows using native sql. But console says me `java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`.
What's wrong? This is my method:

```
public Long getNumRows(Integer id){

        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM controllnews WHERE news_id="
                        + id + ";");
        List firstResult = query.list();

        return (Long) firstResult.get(0);


    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`BigInteger#longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue%28%29) method, instead of casting it to `Long`:

```
return firstResult.get(0).longValue();
```

Seems like `firstResult.get(0)` returns an `Object`. One option is to typecast to `BigInteger`:

```
return ((BigInteger)firstResult.get(0)).longValue();
```

But don't do this. Instead use the way provided by Nambari in comments. I'm no user of Hibernate, so I can't provide Hibernate specific solution.

Comment: (OR) use hibernate scalars http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html

Comment: @Nambari. Oh! I've not used Hibernate though.

Comment: The method longValue() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: And your answer will not work because return type of firstResult.get(0) is Object.

Comment: @JohnSmith. Well, now one option to solve this is to typecast to `BigInteger` first. But the better way would be the one specified by Nambari. You should use it.

Comment: @JohnSmith. Although it works, please look into Hibernate Scalars. That's perhaps the ideal way here.

Comment: nice hack. Seems like EntityManager does NOT have same `scalar` feature as hibernate

Answer (score 4):

I faced same problem, I used Hibernate Scalar queries as suggested in the comment of [@Rohit Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218497/1031945). Thanks [@nambari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094597/nambari) for comment.

Coming to the problem we have,

```
Query query = session
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM controllnews WHERE news_id="
                    + id + ";");
```

These will return a List of Object arrays (Object[]) with scalar values for each column in the `controllnews` table. Hibernate will use ResultSetMetadata to deduce the actual order and types of the returned scalar values.

To avoid the overhead of using ResultSetMetadata, or simply to be more explicit in what is returned, one can use [**addScalar():**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29)

```
Query query = session
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM controllnews WHERE news_id="
                    + id + ";").addScalar("count", LongType.INSTANCE);
```

This will return Object arrays, but now it will not use ResultSetMetadata but will instead explicitly get the `count` column as `Long` from the underlying resultset.

How the `java.sql.Types` returned from ResultSetMetaData is mapped to Hibernate types is controlled by the Dialect. If a specific type is not mapped, or does not result in the expected type, it is possible to customize it via calls to `registerHibernateType` in the Dialect.

---

You can use [Query#setParameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to avoid any mistakes in query as

```
Query query = session
           .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM controllnews WHERE news_id= :id")
           .addScalar("count", LongType.INSTANCE).setParameter("id",id);
```

---

One confusion when you refer [Scalar queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17583) docs 4.0, `addScalar` method has second parameter `Hibernate.LONG`, remember *it has been deprecated since Hibernate version 3.6.X*
[Here is the deprecated document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html), so you have to use `LongType.INSTANCE`

**Related link**

- [Hibernate javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/)

Answer (score 4):

```
  String query ="select count(*) from tablename";       
  Number count = (Number) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).uniqueResult();
  Long value = count.longValue();
```

I tried this it works well