# java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, long-integer, biginteger

I've got `List<Long> dynamics`. And I want to get max result using `Collections`. This is my code:

```
List<Long> dynamics=spyPathService.getDynamics();
        Long max=((Long)Collections.max(dynamics)).longValue();
```

This is my `getDynamics`:

```
public List<Long> getDynamics() {

        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SpyPath WHERE DATE(time)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(time) ORDER BY time;");

        List<Long> result = query.list();
        return result;

    }
```

Now I'm getting `java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`. What's wrong?

Comment: I'd say you're trying to cast a `BigInteger` to a `Long`.

Comment: Because a `java.math.BigInteger` class instance **is not** an instance of `java.lang.Long` class.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more code if you want more help. Maybe the line the error is pointing to? And what type does getDynamics() return?

Comment: you have your answer in your question, i assume this `Collections.max(dynamics))` is `BigInteger`, and you are trying cast it to long, try to cast it to `BigInteger`, and then use `longValue()`method

Comment: Ok people, he's clearly labeled his dynamics list as a `List<Long>`.  @Tony Check the return type of `spyPathService.getDynamics()`.  Assuming your error is actually coming from these lines of code, I would guess from this code that spyPathService.getDynamics() is actually returning a List that at the very least includes some `BigInteger`s

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your error might be in this line:

```
List<Long> result = query.list();
```

where query.list() is returning a BigInteger List instead of Long list. Try to change it to.

```
List<BigInteger> result = query.list();
```

Comment: As @StormeHawke said '...is actually returning a List that at the very least includes some BigIntegers'. So you better find out exactly, before you run into the next problem of this kind.

Comment: This answer lies on wrong assumption about internal Hibernate wrapper types! The only **Aniket Kulkarni** answer *SQLQuery#addScalar* is right!

Comment: I also type cast the list

Answer (score 35):

Better option is use [SQLQuery#addScalar](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29) than casting to `Long` or `BigDecimal`.

Here is modified query that returns `count` column as `Long`

```
Query query = session
             .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as count
                             FROM SpyPath 
                             WHERE DATE(time)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
                             GROUP BY DATE(time) 
                             ORDER BY time;")
             .addScalar("count", LongType.INSTANCE);
```

Then

```
List<Long> result = query.list(); //No ClassCastException here
```

**Related link**

- [Hibernate javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/)
- [Scalar queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17583)
- `Hibernate.LONG`, remember *it has been deprecated since Hibernate version 3.6.X*
  [here is the deprecated document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html), so you have to use `LongType.INSTANCE`
- [My previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950159/1031945)

Comment: You are hero! +1, but really +100!

Answer (score 17):

Try to convert the BigInteger to a long like this

```
Long longNumber= bigIntegerNumber.longValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm lacking context, but this is working just fine:

```
List<BigInteger> nums = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
Long max = Collections.max(nums).longValue(); // from BigInteger to Long...
```

Comment: I heard that `COUNT(*)` statement returns `Long`. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a very old post, but if it benefits anyone, we can do something like this:

```
Long max=((BigInteger) Collections.max(dynamics)).longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure dynamics is a `List<Long>` and not `List<BigInteger>` ?

If dynamics is a `List<Long>` you don't need to do a cast to (Long)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alias for the count to your query and then use the `addScalar()` method as the default for `list()` method in Hibernate seams to be `BigInteger` for numeric SQL types. Here is an example:

```
List<Long> sqlResult = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT column AS num FROM table")
    .addScalar("num", StandardBasicTypes.LONG).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine d.getId is a Long, then wrap like this:

```
BigInteger l  = BigInteger.valueOf(d.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the result as **List of BigInteger** then convert it to a **Long** collection.

```
List<BigInteger> ids = query.getResultList();
Set<Long> collect = ids.stream().map(id -> id.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```