# Trying to create a List of user-defined objects, getting Object List

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my `user.java` domain class is

```
public class User {

private Integer iduser;
private String user_name;
private String user_activation_key;
private String user_password;
private String user_email;
private Character registered;

public Integer getIduser() {
    return iduser;
}

public void setIduser(Integer iduser) {
    this.iduser = iduser;
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}.....more code
```

And in a another Test class I have Coded as follow.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from user");
List<User> availableUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
availableUsers=(List<User>)query.list();
```

**query** is a SQLQuery (Hibernate implementation) to get user list from DB.
But I can't cast the `(query.list)` to `List<User>`.
I'm getting  class cast exception. `availableUser` is a object list.
What steps should I follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HQL

```
SQLQuery query = session.createQuery("from User"); //note here User is POJO class name
List<User> availableUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
availableUsers=(List<User>)query.list();
```

---

### [18.1.1. Scalar queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17583)

These will return a List of Object arrays `(Object[])` with scalar values for each column in the `user` table. Hibernate will use `ResultSetMetadata` to deduce the actual order and types of the returned scalar values.

Use `addScalar()` method when using `createSQLQuery` [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20263999/1031945)

Comment: I used HQL --> Query query = session.createQuery("from user"); and now Im getting a SQLGrammarException

Comment: Exception Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from' at line 1.     **mysql version is 5.5 and hbernate version is 4.3.0**

Comment: @amilaShashin : do not use `session.createSQLQuery()`. See my answer it is `session.createQuery()`.

Comment: I have used session.createQuery(); :)

Comment: @amilaShashin : Is query like `from User`? Note that *U* is in upper case. If this doesn't solve the problem please edit the question and paste the error.

Comment: Thank You Sir.. that was the problem ..I have used 'user' instead of 'User'..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`query.list()` returns `List<Object>`.
Each object is actually an Object array `(Object[])` which has the whole row.

For example, if you are getting all the Employee results, then the list is as follows:-

```
{ {emp_id,emp_name,other_emp_col} , {emp_id,emp_name,other_emp_col}, {emp_id,emp_name,other_emp_col} ....}
```

So for retrieving them you will have to iterate the list of Object and cast iterator.next() into an Object array and then construct your own User object.

For example:-

```
List<Object> userList = query.list();

Iterator<Object> itr = userList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Object[] userRow = (Object[]) itr.next();
    User userObj = new User();
    userObj.setName(userRow[0]);

}
```

To save all these efforts as Aniket said, use HQL