# Errors during Tomcat to WebLogic Server migration for a Springboot project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

Update: I updated the version of mysql connector and am now getting a new error.

So most of these migrations are usually going from WLS to Tomcat. But by default my project has been using Tomcat. My front end is Angular and it is running on port 4200. My backend on tomcat was running on 8080 and all the functions were proper. Now I am trying to deploy this application to my WebLogic Server.

I am now getting this error: 
I tried using [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database), [ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long on connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131295/classcastexception-java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long-on-con)

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.health.doh</groupId>
    <artifactId>timeoff</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>timeoff</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/requester
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

TimeoffApplication.java

```
@ComponentScan 
@SpringBootApplication
public class TimeoffApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRequestDao employeeRequestDao;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TimeoffApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
          return builder.sources(TimeoffApplication.class);
    }
}
```

snippet from Controller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu?

Comment: @olgacosta Thanks, I updated my version of mysql-connecter. However I am facing a new issue.

Comment: Please, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361558/java-math-biginteger-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long